# null values are not being serialized using MassTransit (v8)

Tags: masstransit

We are using MassTransit (8.0.5) with Azure Service Bus as transport and for compatibility with other transports, we still use Newtonsoft and need to include `null` in the messages being sent. The default implementation for null value handling in MassTransit (v8) seems to be `NullValueHandling.Ignore`.

We tried two approaches so far to include null values in the messages:

1. adding attribute `[JsonObject(ItemNullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]` on those properties of our DTOs where we need/expect values to be `null`.
2. configuring the Newtonsoft Json serializer for MassTransit like so:

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((_, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.UseNewtonsoftJsonSerializer();
        cfg.ConfigureNewtonsoftJsonDeserializer(settings =>
        {
            settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
            return settings;
        });
        cfg.ConfigureNewtonsoftJsonSerializer(settings =>
        {
            settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
            return settings;
        });
        cfg.Host(massTransitConnectionString);
    });
});
```

Neither of the methods seem to work as we are not seeing the null values in the messages being sent using service bus.

Here is a fragment of the Json that is being sent:

```json
"secondaryContacts": [
  {
    "contactType": "Unknown"
  },
  {
    "contactType": "Unknown"
  }
],
```

What we except is this:

```json
"secondaryContacts": [
    {
      "contactType": "Unknown",
      "title": null,
      "firstName": null,
      "lastName": null,
      "address": null,
      "email": null,
      "mobilePhone": null,
      "preferredLanguageCode": null
    },
    {
      "contactType": "Unknown",
      "title": null,
      "firstName": null,
      "lastName": null,
      "address": null,
      "email": null,
      "mobilePhone": null,
      "preferredLanguageCode": null
    }
  ],
```

Any help / tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configured as shown below, both `null` and `default` properties are serialized.

```cs
cfg.ConfigureNewtonsoftJsonSerializer(settings =>
{
    settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
    settings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include;
    return settings;
});
cfg.UseNewtonsoftJsonSerializer();
```

> Note the order of operations, the settings are configured, and then the serializer is specified. Also, only the serializer settings are required.